# node mysql cannot access property

Tags: mysql, node.js

Having some trouble parsing the results returned from a node "mysql" query.

Node version 7.8.0
Running CentOS AWS environment.

I developed the node app in Windows Visual Studio CE 2017, and it was working fine, but when porting it to Linux, it's not actually allowing me to access the user_id variable within the results.

I have included lots of variations in trying to access the variable, however the correct one I believe should be:

```
rows[i].user_id
```

All the others are just there as a reference to show that they don't work.

Code:

```
'use strict';
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var mysql = require("mysql");
var con = mysql.createConnection(dbConfig);
con.connect(function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('Error connecting to Db');
            return;
        }
        console.log('Connection established');
});
var q = "select * from table";        
con.query(q, function (err, rows) {
  for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {

    var row = JSON.stringify(rows[i]);
    var rowParsed = JSON.parse(row);
    console.log(row);
    console.log(" row[0].user_id " + row[0].user_id );
    console.log(" row.user_id " + row.user_id );
    console.log(" parsed " + JSON.parse(row));
    console.log(" rowParsed.user_id " + rowParsed.user_id);
    console.log(" rowParsed['user_id'] " + rowParsed['user_id']);
    console.log(" rows[i].user_id " + rows[i].user_id)

    console.log(" rows[i]['user_id'] " + rows[i]['user_id']);
    console.log(rows[i]);

  }
});
```

Results:

```
Connection established
[{"user_id":2}]
 parsed [object Object]
 row[0].user_id undefined
 row.user_id undefined
 rowParsed.user_id undefined
 rowParsed['user_id'] undefined
 rows[i].user_id undefined
 rows[i]['user_id'] undefined
[ RowDataPacket { user_id: 2 } ]
POST /users/register 200 120.026 ms - 22
```

Comment: Why are you calling `stringify` then `parse` in the next line. Just use `var row = rows[i]; console.dir(row);` it will display everything returned from the mysql query. If you want the user id, use `console.log(row[0].user_id);`

Comment: That worked.. Thanks.